# Loading GUIDE in MATLAB results in blank ui panels

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

When I load up my GUI in GUIDE in Matlab, all of the panels are blank. The title is there, but nothing inside the panel is present. To make all of the panel's children appear, I have to move the panel, then CTRL-Z to move it back. After that, everything is present and working.

Is there something that would cause this? Or can I 'refresh' the view without moving the boxes? I don't want to accidentally move something permanently.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result if you did not create your gui within GUIDE.  GUIDE only shows what you created in GUIDE, unfortunately.